# Calculating animation strokeStart based on timestamps?

Tags: ios, swift, logic, caanimation

I'm not 100% sure this is appropriate for stackoverflow as a programming question as it's mostly a math logic problem I'm having a hard time with, so if not my bad.

I'm animating a circle with some of the code below :

```
// Set the animation duration appropriately
    animation.duration = duration

    // Animate from 0 (no circle) to 1 (full circle)
    animation.fromValue = strokeStart
    animation.toValue = 1

    // Do a linear animation (i.e. the speed of the animation stays the same)
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)

    // Set the circleLayer's strokeEnd property to 1.0 now so that it's the
    // right value when the animation ends.
    progressCircle.strokeEnd = 1.0
```

so the key values being worked with are the duration, from value, and the end value which is always going to be 1.

The total 360 degrees of the circle is always going to represent 240 seconds of time (4 minutes).

I set up a function to plug in values for duration and start value when I'm creating the circles, but what I'm having a hard time with is how to calculate those out appropriately.

So for example, when I'm drawing in one of these circles I'm grabbing a timestamp from a server. Let's say the timestamp grabbed was exactly 120 seconds ago. The circle should be drawn in 1/2 way complete already and the rest of the 180 degrees of the circle should be drawn in over the remaining 120 seconds of the total 4 minutes. Another example would just be if a timestamp was done 3 minutes and 50 seconds ago, the circle would basically be filled in immediately by setting the strokeStart to some high percentage and over the next 10 seconds it'd fill up.

I know how to grab the timestamp, I know how to grab how many seconds the timestamp is from the current time, but I don't know how to calculate out the strokeStart.

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the circle is 240 seconds and you know how many seconds have elapsed, simply divide.

```
let strokeStart = Double(secondsElapsed) / 240.0
```

Comment: Haha thank you so much. I don't know why my brain just can't wrap around math. 

Appreciate it a lot.